# What does the {{ syntax on ArrayList initializer really do

Tags: java, arraylist, static-initializer

I have recently found what appears to me to be a new syntax for statically initializing an ArrayList:

```java
new ArrayList<String>() {{
   add("first");
   add("second");
}};
```

My question is, what is really happening there?  Is that a shortcut for defining a static block (I thought it would need the `static` keyword)?  Or just a way to define a default constructor?  Something else?  What version of Java did this become valid?

An explanation plus a link to further reading would be greatly appreciated.

edit:
My test class for showing whether initializer block executes before or after the constructor is below.  Results show that initializer blocks execute before the other constructor code:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class InitializerBlockTest {
    class InitializerTest {
        {
        System.out.println("Running initalizer block");
        }

        public InitializerTest() {
            System.out.println("Running default constructor");
        }
    }
    
    class SubClass extends InitializerTest {
      {
        System.out.println("Running subclass Initializer block");
      }

      public SubClass()  {
        System.out.println("Running subclass constructor");
      }
    }

    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        new SubClass();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Running initalizer block
Running default constructor
Running subclass Initializer block
Running subclass constructor
```

Comment: Where did you find this new syntax?  Do you have a link to an article or something to share?

Comment: BTW: to add to the confusion, you can have any number of static { } and { } blocks anywhere in your class (outside method definitions of course)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization It's by the way not new. Has already been in Java for ages. It's indeed very rarely used, and with a good reason.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372113/meaning-of-new-class-initialization-idiom/1372124#1372124 and others. Difficult one to google.

Comment: Note, your test verifies that the initializer runs before the constructor, but provides no evidence as to when the **super()** call runs relative to the initializer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating a new anonymous subclass of ArrayList, with an instance initializer which calls add() twice.

It's the same as:

```
class MyList extends ArrayList
{

{ // This is an instance initializer; the code is invoked before the constructor.
add("first"); 
add("second");
}

public MyList() {
    super();
    // I believe initializers run here, but I have never specifically tested this
    }
}
```

...

```
List list=new MyList();
```

Note that, personally, I do not advise it as an idiom, since it will lead to class-file explosion.

Comment: Would anyone care to comment on whether the initializer is invoked before or after the super() invocation?

Comment: It would have to be after as super() as always called first.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.  Regarding the before/after, I built a quick test class, and it runs the initializer block before.

Comment: Perhaps you mean, "advise against it"?

Comment: @I82Much: Yes, that is what I meant; fingers won't type what the brain is thinking.

Answer (score 4):

It is an initializer block for instance variables.

From Oracle's documentation:

> Initializer blocks for instance
>   variables look just like static
>   initializer blocks, but without the
>   static keyword:

```
{

    // whatever code is needed for initialization goes here
}
```

> The Java compiler copies initializer
>   blocks into every constructor.
>   Therefore, this approach can be used
>   to share a block of code between
>   multiple constructors.

See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 4):

When you write `new ArrayList() { }` you are creating an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList`. The `{ }` as in the innermost brackets in your code denote an initializer block and is actually copied into every constructor.

EDIT: You guys sure answer fast!