# Initializing a java array

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

Recently, I found that an array can be initialize as follows:

```
private static int[] _array = new int[4];

// An arbitrary amount of code

{ 
    _array[0] = 10;
    _array[1] = 20;
    _array[2] = 30;
    _array[3] = 40;
}
```

What is this form of initialization called? What are its limitations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is instance member initialization using an [initializer block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), and it looks a lot like static initialization which would prefix that block with the word `static`.

Its limitations would match that of any constructor as the Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor. Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between multiple constructors.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this seems like a very dangerous way to initialize an array referenced by a **static** variable.  Each time a new instance is created, the array's previous contents are lost and it is reinitialized to a new set of values.  If that's desirable, then `_array` should probably be an instance member.

Comment: @Mark Pardon my curiosity, but is the difference between "member initialization" and "static initialization" only that the member initialization is called each in each constructor for a new instance, whereas static initialization is called only ever once?

Comment: @T.K.:Semantically, a static initializer is run once each time the class is loaded by the class loader.  In most cases, this means just once.

Comment: @T.K.: member initialization is per *instance* while static initialization is per *class*; so member initialization is called every time a new instance is created, while static initialization will be called only the very first time the class is referenced.

Answer (score 1):

It is initialization block and regarding to [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html):

> The Java compiler copies initializer
>   blocks into every constructor.
>   Therefore, this approach can be used
>   to share a block of code between
>   multiple constructors

I've answered yesterday in similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543437/double-syntax-question-in-java/5543500#5543500)