# Type difference between similar ArrayList declarations

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am trying to create List instance using the following ways:

```
List<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>();

List<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>(){};

List<String> listThree = new ArrayList<String>() {{}};
```

Only `listOne` is initialized as `java.util.ArrayList`, but `listTwo` and `listThree` are not.

What happens in initializing listTwo and listThree and how to understand it better?

My test example is as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>(){};

        List<String> listThree = new ArrayList<String>() {{}};

        System.out.printf("listOne.getClass() == listTwo.getClass() is %b \n",
                listOne.getClass() == listTwo.getClass());

        System.out.printf("listOne.getClass() == listThree.getClass() is %b \n",
                listOne.getClass() == listThree.getClass());

        System.out.printf("listThree.getClass() == listTwo.getClass() is %b \n",
                listThree.getClass() == listTwo.getClass());


        System.out.printf("listOne.getClass() is %s \n",listOne.getClass());

        System.out.printf("listTwo.getClass() is %s \n",listTwo.getClass());

        System.out.printf("listThree.getClass() is %s \n",listThree.getClass());

    }
}
```

Its output in console is as follows:

```
listOne.getClass() == listTwo.getClass() is false 
listOne.getClass() == listThree.getClass() is false 
listThree.getClass() == listTwo.getClass() is false 
listOne.getClass() is class java.util.ArrayList 
listTwo.getClass() is class Test$1 
listThree.getClass() is class Test$2
```

Comment: try to read this post and you will find the answer:
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>(){};
```

This creates an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that extends `ArrayList<String>`. If you do `listTwo instanceof ArrayList`, you'll see that it is, in fact, an `ArrayList` (well, a subclass of one). It's like you made the following class:

```
private class SomeClass extends ArrayList<String>
{
}
```

---

```
List<String> listThree = new ArrayList<String>() {{}};
```

This creates an anonymous class like before, but with an [initialization block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) (which happens to be empty). It's like you created this class:

```
private class SomeClass2 extends ArrayList<String>
{
    {
        // some code could go here...
    }
}
```

This could be used in a [clever-but-confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543437/double-syntax-question-in-java) way, e.g.

```
List<String> listThree = new ArrayList<String>()
{{
    add("hello");
}};
```

This, as you might expect, creates a new list and adds "hello" to it. I'd recommend against this, due to the "confusing" part of that.

In your example, though, all the classes function the same, so you should just use:

```
List<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explainatoin. That makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

In this you crate new instance of class ArrayList

`List<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>();`

Here you define an anonymous class that extend from ArrayList and create new instance of it

`List<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>(){};`

Here you defined an another anonymous class that extend from ArrayList and declare in in initialization block and create an instance of it

`List<String> listThree = new ArrayList<String>() {{}};`

Answer (score 2):

The notation `new ArrayList<String>(){};` instantiate an object of an anonymous class that extends `ArrayList`.

This is why the `class` of your second and third variable are `Test$1` and `Test$2` (this is how the JVM names anonymous class)

Answer (score 0):

`list1` is an `ArrayList`. `list2` is an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList`. `list3` is an anonymous subclass with an initialization block. That means there are three classes involved, of which 2 are anonymous, called `Test$1` and `Test$2`. 1 and 2 refers to the order in which they were declared, `Test` refers to the enclosing class.

Answer (score 0):

The latter two are anonymous subclasses of `ArrayList`. Inside the braces, you can override behavior of the usual original class, as you could using normal inheritance.

For example:

```
List<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>(){
    this.add("hello user!"); //list is automatically initialized with one element
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return super.size() + 1; //this naughty list lies about its size!
    }
};
```

The third one is virtually identical to the second one, it only has an empty code block inside the anonymous class.