# Block Statements in Java

Tags: java, block

I have a class MyMap which extends java.util.HashMap, the following code works as a block of statements but I don't understand the use of the extra curly braces

```
MyMap m = new MyMap() {
  {
      put("some key", "some value");
  }
};
```

Now why do I need the extra curly braces, can't I just do this (but this raises compile error)

```
MyMap m = new MyMap() {
    put("some key", "some value");
};
```

Comment: It's called "double brace initialization". Now, you have new search keywords. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372113/meaning-of-new-class-initialization-idiom, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java

Comment: and it's a dirty hack that should be banned IMO, following it with a initializer (only needs a `;` and putting the name of the var in front of all those methods and maybe an additional `static` following it) does the same without creating a anonymous subclass

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This:

```
MyMap m = new MyMap() {
    ....
};
```

creates an [anonymous inner class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html), which is a subclass of `HashMap`.

This:

```
{
    put("some key", "some value");
}
```

is an [instance initializer](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#246032). The code is executed when the instance of the anonymous subclass is created.

Answer (score 4):

What you're actually doing here is define an *anynomous subclass of MyMap*, which was probably not your intent... The outermost curly braces are around the *class contents*. And in Java, you cannot put instructions directly inside a *class* block: if you need code to be executed when the class is instantiated, you put it into a constructor. That's what the innermost braces are for: they delimit an initializer for your anonymous class.

Now, you probably wanted something like:

```
MyMap m = new MyMap();
m.put("some key", "some value");
```

Just create an instance of `MyMap` and call `put` on it, no anonymous class involved.

Comment: "which was probably not your intent"... actually, this construction is considered idiomatic by some. Seems like overkill to me, though.