# Double brace initialization in JRuby

Tags: java, jruby, double-brace-initialize

I am trying out JRuby, and I was trying to figure out how to use Java's [double brace initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372113/meaning-of-new-class-initialization-idiom/1372124#1372124). However, it is not that apparent how the syntax would be.

To keep this example simple, the below Java code would create a list containing an element:

```
List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>() {{
  add("bar");
}};
```

**Is this possible in JRuby, and if so, *how*?**

`ArrayList.new {{}}` doesn't make sense and results in the error: `odd number list for Hash.puts ArrayList.new({{}})`.

Comment: The [double brace initialization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization) is just creating an anonymous inner subclass of `ArrayList<String>` here.

Comment: Just because JRuby runs on the JVM doesn't mean it brings Java syntax to Ruby.

Comment: @echristopherson I have updated the actual question so it doesn't sound too "demanding".

Comment: The double-brace initialization is a hacky workaround because Java doesn't have literal constructors like Ruby has. Why on earth wouldn't you just want to use the Ruby syntax?

Comment: @MarkThomas In my opinion, I think it's cleaner to have the logic which has to do with initialization enclosed inside the braces.

Comment: @whirlwin Cleaner than the alternate Java syntax, because Java lacks literal constructors for basic types. But not cleaner than Ruby syntax.

Comment: @MarkThomas Yes, but can I pass a block to ArrayList's constructur at all?

Comment: @MarkThomas NVM, I figured it out by passing a Ruby Array into ArrayList's constructor. `ArrayList.new Array.new(10) { 42 }`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do double curly brace initialization in JRuby. But for things like ArrayList Initialization JRuby offers shortcuts as in example below.

Please check https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby for details.

```
>> a = ArrayList.new [:a, :b, "c", "d"]
#<Java::JavaUtil::ArrayList:0x65a953>
>> a[0]
:a
>> a[1]
:b
>> a[2]
"c"
>> a[3]
"d"
>> a[4]
nil
```

Answer (score 1):

While not a direct answer to the question, am I adding this because this is a convenient way of having some logic determine what each element will be. This is done passing a Ruby Array into ArrayList's constructor.

```
ArrayList.new Array(10) {|i| i*i}
```

Thanks to [Mark Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182590/mark-thomas) for helping me think. :)