# Fill hash map during creation

Tags: java, collections, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Initialise a static Map in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-to-initialise-a-static-map-in-java)

How to fill HashMap in Java at initialization time, is possible something like this ?

```
public static Map<byte,int> sizeNeeded=new HashMap<byte,int>(){1,1};
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`byte`, `int` are primitive, collection works on object. You need something like this:

```java
public static Map<Byte, Integer> sizeNeeded = new HashMap<Byte, Integer>() {{
    put(new Byte("1"), 1);
    put(new Byte("2"), 2);
}};
```

This will create a new `map` and using [*initializer block*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) it will call put method to fill data.

Comment: Not me, but probably because of `new Byte((byte) 1)`.. and maybe not relying on autoboxing.. And the not used `;` at the end of the init clause.. just looks ugly!

Comment: @dacwe  thanks for pointing out that cast thing.

Comment: -1 from be because I think this is a horrible abuse, and you're not even explaining what it is.

Comment: @Mich agree. added info. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can't have primitives as generic type parameters in Java, so `Map<byte,int>` is impossible, it'll have to be `Map<Byte,Integer>`.

Second, no, there are no collection literals in Java right now, though they're being considered as a new feature in [Project Coin](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/coin/). Unfortunately, they were dropped from Java 7 and you'll have to wait until Java 8...