# Create Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

I'd like to create a `map` that contains entries consisting of `(int, Point2D)`

How can I do this in Java?

I tried the following unsuccessfully.

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap();

hm.put(1, new Point2D.Double(50, 50));
```

Answer (score 155, accepted):

```
Map <Integer, Point2D.Double> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Point2D>();
hm.put(1, new Point2D.Double(50, 50));
```

Comment: You also must do
`import java.util.Map; import java.util.HashMap;`
or `import java.util.*;`

Comment: you may choose avoid the second pair of class names, i.e. `Map <Integer, Point2D.Double> hm = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 36):

There is even a better way to create a Map along with initialization:

```
Map<String, String> rightHereMap = new HashMap<String, String>()
{
    {
        put("key1", "value1");
        put("key2", "value2");
    }
};
```

For more options take a look here [How can I initialise a static Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-can-i-initialise-a-static-map)

Comment: This is a really **bad** way to initalize a map.

Comment: @Kao Why? This just visually contains the operation, otherwise it's identical to the top answer on this question.

Comment: No, it's not. It is a double-brace initialization, which is, generally speaking, an anti-pattern. [Here is why](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/08/dont-be-clever-the-double-curly-braces-anti-pattern/).

Comment: It's a weird code, I agree.

Comment: This is perfect for creating a static map in unit test

Answer (score 30):

**Java 9**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer,String> map = Map.ofEntries(entry(1,"A"), entry(2,"B"), entry(3,"C"));
}
```

Answer (score 21):

With the newer Java versions (*i.e.,*  Java 9 and forwards) you can use :

```
Map.of(1, new Point2D.Double(50, 50), 2, new Point2D.Double(100, 50), ...)
```

generically:

```
Map.of(Key1, Value1, Key2, Value2, KeyN, ValueN)
```

Bear in mind however that [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-) only works for **at most** `10` entries, if you have more than `10` entries that you can use :

```
Map.ofEntries(entry(1, new Point2D.Double(50, 50)), entry(2,  new Point2D.Double(100, 50)), ...);
```

Answer (score 11):

```
Map<Integer, Point2D> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Point2D>();
```

Comment: `Point2D.Double` doesn't look as a `Point2D` =\

Comment: using `Map<int, Point2D> hm = new HashMap<int, Point2D>()`, I get this error:  Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token.

Comment: Forgot that Java maps don't support primitive types. Fixed that.

Comment: but I need Point2D as the value in the [key, value]. :/

Comment: That was what I initially wrote.

Answer (score 6):

I use such kind of a Map population thanks to Java 9. In my honest opinion, this approach provides more readability to the code.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Point2D.Double> map = Map.of(
        1, new Point2D.Double(1, 1),
        2, new Point2D.Double(2, 2),
        3, new Point2D.Double(3, 3),
        4, new Point2D.Double(4, 4));
    map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
  }
```