# How to initialize a static SparseArray

Tags: java, android, collections, initialization, sparse-array

How can I initialize a `static`, unmodifiable instance of [`android.util.SparseArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html)?

Comment: You don't initialize static properties. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Eric the SparseArray equivalent of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/507658/884677 for a static map

Comment: @Eric yes, exactly as I stated in this question, and the linked question/answer

Comment: You're better off using a HashMap for this purpose.  I tried tackling the same problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot do what you are attempting to. At least, not how you are attempting to do it. There is no implementation of `SparseArray` that is unmodifiable.

However, you could create one. Here's how:

- Create a class, say `CustomSparseArray<E>`, and have it extend `SparseArray`.
- Override **all methods** that change the elements in the array, and replace them with something like this:

  ```
  @Override
  public void append(int key, E value) {
      if (mLocked)
          return; // Maybe throw an exception
      super.append(key, value);
  }
  ```
- Then, add in a member variable to the class, `boolean mLocked = false;`.
- Next, you need a method like the following:

  ```
  public void lock() { mLocked = true; }
  ```
- Lastly, implement your static variable using a method similar to in [the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/507658/884677):

  ```
  public class Test {
      private static final CustomSparseArray<Integer> myArray;
      static {
          myArray = new CustomSparseArray<Integer>();
          myArray.append(1, 1);
          myArray.append(2, 5);
          myArray.lock();
      }
  }
  ```

Then you have an unmodifiable `SparseArray` in your `static` variable `myArray`.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a better way using an anonymous class:

```
static final SparseIntArray myArray = new SparseIntArray() {
    {
        append(1, 2);
        append(10, 20);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
static final SparseIntArray CMyArray = new SparseIntArray();
static {
    CMyArray.append(2, 4);
    CMyArray.append(8, 3);
    CMyArray.append(255, 1);
}
```

as per: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html