# How to freeze a HashMap to prevent further changes?

Tags: java, data-structures

The question is pretty much self-explanatory. I have a data structure (I mentioned a `HashMap` but it could be a Set or a List also) which I initially populate:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

for( something ) {
  map.put( something );
}
```

After the structure has been populated, I never want to add or delete any items:

```
map.freeze();
```

How could one achieve this using standard Java libraries?

Comment: If you are always populating it directly after initializing, why not use static initialization? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-to-initialise-a-static-map-in-java) is a good example of how to do that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best you can do with standard JDK libraries is [`Collections.unmodifiableMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29).

Note that you *must* drop the original map reference, because that reference can still be accessed and changed normally. If you passed the old reference to any other objects, they still will be able to change your map.

Best practice:

```
map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
```

and make sure you didn't share the original `map` reference.

Comment: Not quite correct. If you're concerned that someone might mutate the original map, you can make a defensive copy of it. `map - Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<K,V>(map));` Of course, this still leaves the question of whether any of the objects in the map are themselves mutable.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you would do very well with Guava's [`ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html). Which allows use of the Builder pattern to assemble and "freeze".

Comment: And this is the best solution there is if you can use 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Yes, but the questions asks: *How could one achieve this using **standard Java libraries**?*

Comment: Sometimes the answer you want is not the answer you need.

Comment: Please don't link to the old google-collections site; use the guava-libraries site.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in a class and make it immutable. For example:

```
public class ImmutableMapWrapper {

    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ImmutableMapWrapper() {
        for( something ) {
            this.map.put( something );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an immutable HashMap:

```
HashMap <MyKey, MyValue> unmodifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(modifiableMap);
```

JavaDoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29).

Also, I think the Google data collections utils (Guava???) has an ImmutableMap type already.