# What is a good switch statement alternative?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a string array containing strings of 3 letters each. Every 3 letters (every element) corresponds to a unique letter. I need to create a char array from the string array.

The only way i can think of doing this is looping through each element in the array of strings and using a long switch statement to determine its associated single character.

What other ways can this be accomplished?

Comment: This is a chicken and egg problem -- if you had a data structure that you could use in place of a switch statement, then you wouldn't need to code a solution at all: you'd have the data structure you need already

Comment: Is there some function that determines what the single letter corresponding to each string is?  It seems like the most direct approach, if there is, would be to implement that function.

Comment: Are the 3-letter strings also unique, or can different strings be mapped to the same letter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a mapping/lookup then usually a map/dictionary solves your problem. An example such structure in C#:

```
string[] inList = new[]{"bee", "kay", "kay", "eff" }; 
Dictionary<string, char> mapping = new Dictionary<string, char> 
   { 
       {"bee", 'b'},
       {"eff", 'f'},
       {"kay", 'k'},
   };
```

If you have such a mapping, then just look up the letters from the mapping, or convert the whole list of strings to an array of chars.

```
char[] chars = inList.Select(s => mapping[s]).ToArray();
```

Almost all languages supports data structures of this type, although not all support functional constructs like the last snippet. In that case you need a loop to build the out array.

EDIT: Saw you added the java tag. You can accomplish the same in java, your dictionary will then be a `HashMap` in java. So just take an aspirin and look at [How can I initialise a static Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-to-initialise-a-static-map-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is a [Hashmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) mapping from string to char

Answer (score 2):

what language are you using?

you could set up a look-up table using an array like so:

lookuptable = { {'a','abc'},{'b','abd'} ....}

then you just look up the corresponding value in the array.

if your language supports dictionaries, it'll be even easier.

Comment: I am using the Java language

Comment: Based on the Q, I think the 3 char strings should be the keys in the map. Otherwise, this is the right idea. +1

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Enum to define your elements and the corresponding character.  Then have a method that decrypts the value.

Example:

```
public enum EncryptedValue {

    A ("A", "EDK"),
    B ("B", "CHI"),
    C ("C", "WAD"),
    ...;

    private String value;
    private String encryption;

    private static final List<EncryptedValue> VALUES = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(values()));

    private EncryptedValue(String value, String encryption) {
        this.value = value;
        this.encryption = encryption;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getEncryption() {
        return encryption;
    }

    public String decrypt(Strign encryption) {
        for (EncryptedValue encryptedValue : VALUES) {
            if (encryptedValue.getEncryption().equalsIgnoreCase(encyrption))
                return encryptedValue.getValue();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```