# NullPointerException when attempting ConcurrentHashMap.get()

Tags: java, spring

I have the following code:

```
public class MyEvent implements org.apache.camel.Processor
{
    static private final Map<Long, String> obj = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, String>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() 
    {
        for (Object object : cacheList) 
        {
            obj.put(object.getId(), object.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception 
    {
        synchronized (obj) 
        {
            String value = obj.get(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes when starting, I have a `NullPointerException` in this line:

```
String value = obj.get(number);
```

My question is: Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Java version 1.6.0_32

Comment: Where do you define number? ConcurrentHashMap get method could throw NPE if key is null.

Comment: what is `number` parameter there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Where is `number` defined?  Also, I think you need a static initializer for your map if you want to make it final. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-can-i-initialize-a-static-map) might be helpful

Comment: As a side note: Java 1.6 is no longer supported. You should upgrade.

Comment: i cannot do a static initialization, because of other limitations.

Comment: You still haven't edited your question to show us where `number` is defined and set, or explained what it is used for. When you do that, you can also explain why you can't initialize it.

Comment: "number" is inited from other objects, so indeed this could be the problem, i wrote below also the stacktrace i get.

Comment: by the way, you shouldn't be synchronizing on the collection as a lock `synchronized (obj)` that's totally wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object))

Method get will throws `NullPointerException`  if the key is null

I will suggest you to perform null check on `number` before you will call get

Comment: i think the problem indeed can be in "number". 
because i have the following stacktrace:
**CaughtExceptionType:java.lang.NullPointerException, CaughtExceptionMessage:null, StackTrace:java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:917)
        at MyEvent.process(MyEvent.java:61)**
where 61 is the line i mentioned. I will check and if something i will come with an update.