# What is the Android Java equivalent of a Swift Dictionary?

Tags: java, android, swift, dictionary

In swift I can declare a dictionary (key value pairs) like so

```
var toppings = [
        "Onions":"Red",
        "Peppers":"Green",
    ]
```

What is the equivalent (declare key value pairs) in Java?

I have tried modifying an array i.e. changing...

```
public String[] couplets = {
        "Onions",
        "Peppers",
};
```

...to...

```
 public String[] toppings = {
        "Onions":"Red",
        "Peppers":"Green",
};
```

...but it does not work.

I appreciate they are different languages so likely I am oversimplifying this by trying to do a straight like for like.

Essentially I would like to create a static list of key value pairs in Java.

I have googled for suggestions but all the answers seem overly complicated compared to what I can do in swift so I am wondering if there is a straightforward way - Perhaps there isn't...

Any advice is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-can-i-initialize-a-static-map

Comment: The answer is in the tag wiki for [tag:dictionary].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

> A Map is an object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys: Each key can map to at most one value.

```
Map<String,String> toppings = new HashMap<>();
toppings.put("Onions","Red");
toppings.put("Peppers","Green");
```

Maps are great, you will end up using them a lot :)

Comment: Thanks Ken this is exactly what I was looking for, 1 question .put seems to be giving me an error - do I need to import something for this method to work?

Comment: You shouldn't need to import anything and `.put` shouldn't give you an error if you have defined `toppings` as above. Anyway, your IDE should tell you what the error is which should give you a clue to solving it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the Map.**

Instanciate new Map :

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Put values :

```
map.put("Onions","Red");
```

Read values :

`map.get("Onions");` will return "Red"

Comment: You should declare it as a Map, not a HashMap. Program to the interface, not to the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need work with a String key you should use an `HashMap` as suggested in other answers.

If you can use an Integer key, I suggest you using a [SparseArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html)

```
SparseArray<String> values = new SparseArray<String>();
values.put(1,"value1");
values.put(2,"value2");
```