# JavaFX Listview Observe Map

Tags: java, listview, dictionary, javafx, observers

I have a HashMap. I want to display the Keys in a ListView.

The trouble is, ListView.setItems() wants an ObservableList, and all I have is a keySet().

How can I get a ListView to observe the keys in my Map, without doing something clunky like maintaining two matching data structures?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this is not the answer you want, but... my advice is to maintain two data structures.

**Sample App (synching data structures)**

Add items to a map using the UI on the right and, as the keys in the `extension -> mimeType` map change, you will see the list of keys shown in the ListView on the left automatically update.

The solution listens for changes to an ObservableMap which wraps the `extension -> mimetype` map and, when a key in the map changes, applies relevant updates to an ObservableList which backs the ListView.

In the sample screenshot below, `png` will be added to the left hand side list when the user presses the Add button.

[image: mapobserver]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ObservableMapTest extends Application {
    // map initializer based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/25829097/1155209
    private static final Map<String, String> extensionToMimeMap =
            Arrays.stream(new String[][]{
                    {"txt", "text/plain"},
                    {"html", "text/html"},
                    {"js", "application/javascript"},
                    {"css", "text/css"}
            }).collect(Collectors.toMap(kv -> kv[0], kv -> kv[1]));

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // create an observable wrapper for our map data.
        final ObservableMap<String, String> observableExtensionToMimeMap = FXCollections.observableMap(
                extensionToMimeMap
        );

        // create an ListView based on key items in the map.
        ListView<String> extensionListView = new ListView<>();
        extensionListView.getItems().setAll(extensionToMimeMap.keySet());
        extensionListView.setPrefWidth(100);

        // have the ListView observe the underlying map and modify its items if the key set changes.
        observableExtensionToMimeMap.addListener((MapChangeListener<String, String>) change -> {
            extensionListView.getItems().removeAll(change.getKey());
            if (change.wasAdded()) {
                extensionListView.getItems().add(change.getKey());
            }
        });

        // layout the app.
        Pane layout = new HBox(
                extensionListView,
                createAddExtensionPane(
                        observableExtensionToMimeMap
                )
        );
        layout.setPrefHeight(150);

        // display the app.
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    /** Helper factory function to create a UI for adding an element to an map. */
    private GridPane createAddExtensionPane(Map<String, String> map) {
        GridPane addExtensionPane = new GridPane();

        addExtensionPane.add(new Label("Extension:"), 0, 0);
        TextField extensionField = new TextField();
        addExtensionPane.add(extensionField, 1, 0);

        addExtensionPane.add(new Label("Mime Type:"), 0, 1);
        TextField mimeTypeField = new TextField();
        addExtensionPane.add(mimeTypeField, 1, 1);

        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(event ->
                map.put(
                        extensionField.getText(),
                        mimeTypeField.getText()
                )
        );
        addExtensionPane.add(addButton, 1, 2);
        addExtensionPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        addExtensionPane.setHgap(5);
        addExtensionPane.setVgap(10);

        return addExtensionPane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

A possible alternate implementation which did not copy data into an ObservableList would be to implement the ObservableList interface and in the implemented methods refer directly to the key data of the observable map.  Such an approach would be very complex to implement and not worthwhile pursuing (IMO).

Comment: That was a great, detailed answer. Thank you!