# In Java, can I declare a HashMap constant?

Tags: java, hashmap, constants

I am writing a simple program to convert a number to a word representing that number (13 => "thirteen").

I realize I could get some of the words with a constant String array like this:

```
private static final String[] tensNames = {"", " ten", " twenty", " thirty", " forty", " fifty", " sixty", " seventy", " eighty", " ninety" };
```

...and access it with the index, but I wanted to try it with a HashMap like this:

```
final HashMap<Integer, String> tensNumberConversion = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    tensNumberConversion.put(2, "twenty");
    tensNumberConversion.put(3, "thirty");
    tensNumberConversion.put(4, "forty");
    tensNumberConversion.put(5, "fifty");
    tensNumberConversion.put(6, "sixty");
    tensNumberConversion.put(7, "seventy");
    tensNumberConversion.put(8, "eighty");
    tensNumberConversion.put(9, "ninety");
```

I was instructed by a teacher to make these constants.  Can the HashMap be a constant? As a newbie, it wasn't totally clear how the terms "constant" and "static" and "final" are related, and what exactly makes a constant. (static alone?  final alone?  static final together?).

I tried making it private static final Hashmap but IntelliJ gave me an error (modifier 'private' not allowed here...same for 'static').

However, it does compile from my terminal with no errors. If a HashMap can be a constant, is this the right way to declare one? Thanks!

Comment: It can be a constant, where are you declaring your `HashMap`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I initialise a static Map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-can-i-initialise-a-static-map)

Comment: According to what I see, I accepted your answer on May 12th.  Is that different from what you see?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two aspects here:

- You have a variable that holds a reference to a map. You simply declare that variable to be *final*; and voilà, you can't change the variable to point to *another* reference.
- But that doesn't prevent you from changing the *state* of the object that reference is pointing. So even when you have a *final Map* object, you could still call put/remove/... methods on that Map.

So, in order to come to a real "constant" Map, you do go for this:

First you create an ordinary map containing all the desired values.

Then you use `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` in order to create a map that can't be changed any more.

The one thing to pay attention to: you have to make sure that you are not leaking a reference to the original map object as that immutable map is just a wrapper around that initial map. You could do that in a little helper method for example.

If you are asking: is there a way to write down a map declaration in a special "literal form" (like for arrays) - there isn't. Well, you can change that helper method to take `Object ...` as parameter; and then you would go through those parameters, one is a number, next one a string, and use that to fill the map. So you could then invoke the method with a single sequence of values. But probably not worth the effort ...

A quick update: Java9 added various static helper methods that allow you write down maps in a somehow "literal" way, see [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-immutable-set-list-and-map-in-java-9) for example.

Comment: Collections.unmodifiableMap

Answer (score 52):

Yes, it can be a constant. You should declare your `HashMap` instance as follows:

```
class <class name> {
    private static final HashMap<Integer, String> tensNumberConversion = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        tensNumberConversion.put(2, "twenty");
        tensNumberConversion.put(3, "thirty");
        tensNumberConversion.put(4, "forty");
        tensNumberConversion.put(5, "fifty");
        tensNumberConversion.put(6, "sixty");
        tensNumberConversion.put(7, "seventy");
        tensNumberConversion.put(8, "eighty");
        tensNumberConversion.put(9, "ninety");
    }
}
```

However, this is only a constant reference. While you can not reassign `tensNumberConversion` to something else, you still can change the contents of your map later at runtime:

```
tensNumberConversion = new HashMap<>(); // won't compile
tensNumberConversion.put(9, "one"); // succeeds
```

If you want the contents of your map constant too, you should wrap the `HashMap` into an unmodifiable map:

```
class <class name> {
    private static final Map<Integer, String> tensNumberConversion = initMap();

    private static Map<Integer, String> initMap() {
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(2, "twenty");
        map.put(3, "thirty");
        map.put(4, "forty");
        map.put(5, "fifty");
        map.put(6, "sixty");
        map.put(7, "seventy");
        map.put(8, "eighty");
        map.put(9, "ninety");
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: Much better now.

Answer (score 25):

Just a BTW, with Java 9 there are [static methods in the `Map` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries-java.util.Map.Entry...-) to create immutable Maps with some number of entries like:

```
Map<String,String> m = Map.of("k1", "v1",
                              "K2", "v2");
```

Or if more than 10 entries are needed:

```
import static java.util.Map.entry;
Map<String, String> m = Map.ofEntries(
    entry("k1", "v1"), entry("k2", "v2"), …);
```

Comment: Anyway, map.of or map.ofEntry will maintain order?

Comment: I think it's only guaranteed for SortedMap implementations and LinkedHashMap. Map.of specifically mentions that the iteration order is unspecified. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#immutable

Answer (score 14):

I somehow missed the easiest form for direct initialization of the HashMap here

```
private static final Map<Integer, String> tensNumberConversion_internal = new HashMap<Integer, String>()
{
    {
        put(2, "twenty");
        put(3, "thirty");
        put(4, "forty");
        put(5, "fifty");
        put(6, "sixty");
        put(7, "seventy");
        put(8, "eighty");
        put(9, "ninety");
    };
};
```

and as for making it unchangeable you already have `Collections.unmodifiableMap` from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43906280/7111561) so do

```
public static final Map<Integer, String> tensNumberConversion = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tensNumberConversion_internal);
```

they have to be created in this order ofcourse ;)

Comment: I would not call that the "simplest" form, the double-brace initialization trick is quite a heavy hack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using composting to achieve a constant HashMap, you could use inheritance to inherit a new class from HashMap and then override the HashMap.put() method to display some appropriate failure message...

`class MyMap extends java.util.HashMap{

    @Override

    public V put (K key, V value){

         System.out.println("Operation Not Supported");

         return null;

    }

}`

Note that this is not the only method but one of the many methods possible

Comment: but that is basically what the map returned by [`Collections.unmodifiableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap-java.util.Map-) already does - except that it throws instead of pretending to work - all modifying methods throw UnsupportedOperationException.